# $X_n$ is a discrete random process. $P(X_n=2)=P(X_n=-2)=0.5$ for all $n$ Find autocovariance function of $X_n$.

Tags: probability, covariance, variance

Find the autocovariance function of $X_n$
$$E[X_n]=E[X(n)]=0.5\cdot2+0.5\cdot (-2)=0$$
$$E[X_{n}^2]=E[[X(n)]^2]=0.5\cdot2^2+0.5(-2)^2=4$$
The autocorrelation function
$$R_{XX}(n_1,n_2)=E[X(n_1)X(n_2)]=E[X(n_1)(X(n_1)+X(n_2)-X(n_1))]=E[X^2(n_1)]-E[X(n_1)]E[X(n_2)-X(n_1)]=E[X^2(n_1)]=4$$ assuming that $n_2>n_1$ What is next?

Comment: Just knowing the marginals does not tell you the covariance, you need to know how they depend on each other. In particular the covariance could be anything between $-4$ and $4$.

Comment: So if they are random how they can depend on each other?

Comment: Consider for instance the case of two random variables $X_1,X_2$ which can each be $-1$ or $1$ with equal probability. Then their joint distribution assigns $(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1)$ certain probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ with the requirement that $p_1+p_2=1/2$ and $p_3+p_4=1/2$. Otherwise $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ can be anything. If they are all $1/4$ then $X_1,X_2$ are independent, otherwise they are dependent.

Comment: Sorry, $p_1+p_2=1/2,p_3+p_4=1/2,p_1+p_3=1/2,p_2+p_4=1/2$. This is four linear equations in four unknowns....but one of them is redundant to the other three, so there is a free parameter ($p_4$, say). Tuning this free parameter from $0$ to $1$ changes the covariance from $-1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $m>0$:
$$\begin{align}E[X(n)X^*(n+m)]=(2)(2)(0.5)(0.5)+(-2)(2)(0.5)(0.5)+(2)(-2)(0.5)(0.5)+(-2)(-2)(0.5)(0.5)=0\end{align}$$
When $m=0$:

$E[X(n)X(n+m)]=E[|X(n)|^2]=0.5(-2)^2+0.5(2)^2=4$

Therefore, $$R_{XX}(n,n+m)=R_{XX}(m)=4\delta(m)$$
which means the process is uncorrelated.

Since
$$E[X]=0.5(2)+0.5(-2)=0$$

The autocovariance function $$C_{XX}(m)=R_{XX}(m)-(E[X])^2=4\delta(m)$$

Comment: Are you assuming independence here somehow? As I said in my comment, you can have these one-dimensional distributions and still have the covariance be any number between $-4$ and $4$.

Comment: No I just assume it is WSS. since it says "for all $n$".

Comment: You didn't state that assumption, nor was that assumption given. Being weak-sense stationary does not follow from the one-dimensional distribution being constant.

Comment: All $n$ means SSS which is higher that WSS.

Comment: That still doesn't tell you about the joint distributions. Consider all the possible 2 dimensional distributions with this property. There are many of these!

Comment: I know that the $n$-fold pdf is required in general.The question title is ambiguous in that sense (there are different interpretatins from "all $n$" part). For clarity, It should have said explicitly that they are iid otherwise we need the joint pdf.